# Directly Print PDF in client side without viewing it

Tags: asp.net, pdf, printing, dom-events, c#-3.0

I have PDF file in server, when user clicks print button on my asp.net page I need to show print dialogue directly without showing the PDF. How can I achieve this? Please guide me.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible using only JavaScript.  There may be a solution using Flash, though.

Answer (score 2):

This only works in IE, but you can embed the Adobe ActiveX control into an HTML page as follows:

```
<object classid="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" style="height:75%; width: 100%; display: none;" id="viewer" name="viewer" VIEWASTEXT>
    <param name="src" value="document.pdf">
</object>
```

Then in the onclick of the print button you can do this:

```
viewer.printWithDialog();
```

Might be able to tweak this for other browsers.

Comment: When the code call this method - viewer.Print(); throws error like object doesnot support this method.

Comment: Here is a URL for the documentation for the Adobe ActiveX control. There are other methods you can try. We are doing this today in IE using VBScript, so I know it works :)

http://www.cgplusplus.com/online-reference/maxscript-reference/source/adobe_acrobat_activex_control.htm

Comment: Actually - we are printing WITH OUT the dialog using a regedit hack. I think you need to call .printWithDialog() instead... I edited my post above to reflect.